# a.exe file is not showing in vs code for c++ code (hello world)

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

i have written my first code in vs code and tried to compile the code using MingW g++(installed and did that copied the bin address inside environmental variables)
a.exe file is not shown which should have been shown as per youtube tutorial
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVTaU.png)

Comment: What's your build command? Did you look in the directory you build to if there's a file?

Comment: There is a linker error due to the appropriate `main` function not being defined.

Comment: Did you have implemented the main function ? `int main() { /* do something */; return 0; }`

Comment: Int main is there